# How to get sub ranges from pivot table

Tags: excel

I have a table like this

```
col1    col2
a   1
a   2
a   3
a   4
a   5
b   6
b   7
b   8
b   9
b   10
```

I want to write a PERCENTILE function for each group in col1. Is there a way by pivoting this table and writing custom function PERCENTILE. But calculated field in pivot table is not allowing to write functions. I have to do this without VBA

I have to write, to find average of top 70%, something like below. But how to get sub ranges?

```
col1    col2
a   =AVERAGEIF(B1:B5,">"&Percentile(B1:B5,0.7))
b   =AVERAGEIF(B6:B10,">"&Percentile(B6:B10,0.7))
```

Comment: Please rephrase it as a question, and if you can, describe the problem more clearly, please.  As it is, I am really not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @AJMansfield hope my edit explains my need. thank you

Comment: Have you looked at all the Value Field Settings. As I have done this before and am almost certain It was a built it part of the PT.... Right click the column go to value field settings, and summarize by AND display values as. you might have to dig around a little but I do remember accomplishing this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with an array formula since the percentile function accepts arrays:

```
=PERCENTILE(IF($A$2:$A$11=D2,$B$2:$B$11,""),0.7)
```

[image: Example1]

This needs to be entered as an array formula with ctrl+shift+enter.

```
{=PERCENTILE(IF($A$2:$A$11=D2,$B$2:$B$11,""),0.7)}
```

[image: Example2]

Just auto-fill that down the column. Let me know if you need an example of how to copy-paste the unique values of a column.

You can test it like so if you want. It works:

```
=PERCENTILE(B7:B11,0.7)
```

[image: Example3]

Good Luck.